# Getting element text from a source xml file with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am brand new to XSL and am trying to get the information from a source file that is in this format:

```
<mailList>
    <subscriber familyname="Smith"
                givenname="Jon"
                email="js@somewhere.com"/>
    <subscriber givenname="Luke"
                familyname="Sky"
                email="sov.com"/>
```

I have tried to use value-of but it just creates an empty element:

```
<xsl:template match="subscriber">
    <xsl:element name="entry">
      <xsl:element name="firstname">
        <xsl:value-of select="forename"></xsl:value-of>
      </xsl:element>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:template match="subscriber">` is fine for matching any of the `subscriber` input elements. Inside of that template you can select the data with e.g. `xsl:value-of`, but of course you have to select existing data, your attempt of `select="forename"` tries to select a child element of that name. Your `subscriber` elements don't have any child elements at all, there are only attributes, even those don't have that name `forename`.

To select an attribute you use e.g. `select="@attribute-name"`, so for your sample e.g. `select="@givenname"`.

As for creating result elements, while `<xsl:element name="entry">` is possible, you can use literal result elements e.g.

```
  <entry>
    <firstname>
      <xsl:value-of select="@givenname"/>
    </firstname>
  </entry>
```